Split a polygon in many parts by areas of specified values
I try to split a polygon in multiple parts based on known values. For example, if I have a 1000 sqm polygon i need to be splitted in 4 polygons (100 sqm, 600 sqm, 50 sqm and the rest of the polygon).
Can it be done in ArcGIS Pro?

From the duplicate, this is what I think you should try: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/subdivide-polygon.htm
